# AWS CodePipeline (GitHub > CodeBuild > Elastic Beanstalk) for Java Maven Web App .war Project - buildspec.yml Getting Error

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

Not managed to find where I'm going wrong here reading the guides from AWS and lots of things online.

Two problems I'm seeing with various configurations.

**Problem 1 - Producing a .zip File rather than a .war file**

This buildspec.yml file works, but it produces a .zip file not a .war file, so it ends up failing on the Deploy stage in the pipeline;

```
version: 0.2
 
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn clean install 
artifacts:
  files:
    - target/MyApp.war
  discard-paths: yes
```

**Problem 2 - AWS Docs Don't Work**

So I followed the AWS guides, as best as possible as they are awful, and ended up with the following buildspec.yml file and the additional /.ebextensions/fix-path.config file;

```
version: 0.2
 
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
  post_build:
    commands:
      - mvn package
      - mv target/ROOT.war ROOT.war
artifacts:
  files:
    - ROOT.war
    - .ebextensions/**/*
```

Which now produces the following error

```
[Container] 2023/09/02 21:27:32 Running command mv target/ROOT.war ROOT.war
mv: cannot stat ‘target/ROOT.war’: No such file or directory

[Container] 2023/09/02 21:27:32 Command did not exit successfully mv target/ROOT.war ROOT.war exit status 1
[Container] 2023/09/02 21:27:32 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/09/02 21:27:32 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: mv target/ROOT.war ROOT.war. Reason: exit status 1
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?